# how to get the coefficients for a dependent continues categorical variable

Tags: r, regression, glm

I have a question regarding regression analysis in R. It would be nice if you could please help. I have a dependent continuous categorical variable. This variable is actually the number of citations received by three groups of papers: female-authored papers, male-authored papers, female-male-authored papers. I have also several co-variates which could be categorical or continuous. My factor variable is a continuous variable.

With the kind of data that I have (over dispersed and have an excess of zeros), hurdle regression model seems to be the best model. I can run the regression model in R using  threes libraries of MASS, pscl and AER. The only problem that I have is how to get the coefficients for all three groups of papers, so that I will be able to compare them.

Comment: This probably needs stats advice (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions), but as is, the question is a little unclear (at least to me); specifically *continuous categorical variable*, and *factor variable is a continuous*. Can you post a small example of your data which may make things a bit clearer please. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) shows some ways of how to share / generate representative data.

Comment: can you post an example if the model youre trying to run? your DV doesnt sound continuous, but rather a count of the number of papers, and one of your IVs will be categorical (male, female, male-female). but then you say that your factor variable is continuous, but I guess this is not referring to the 3 groups you mentioned...?